# sound drivers don't work or I can not fix my settings

Tags: drivers, audio

I tried both headphones and speakers and I plug them correctly I am sure.
I can't hear anything and I can't record my voice either.
here is the snapshot of my device manager

[image]

I am newbie about windows 7 before,I had win Xp I think I should install drivers but I don't know what should I search and install also I don't have my driver CDs

what can I do?

is it possible that maybe my settings have problems and the drivers are installed perfectly?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Windows 7 [Audio Playback Troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-the-Playing-Audio-troubleshooter)?  What does it say?

Comment: @techie007 Thank you I tried,it told me it wasn't default and fixed it but still I can't hear anything in down direction in the speakers when I click on them the sound is moving with the green color but I can't hear.

Answer (score 0):

Likley the HD audio driver is missing.  Who made the computer?  Their web site may have teh driver you need.  If an Intel Motherboard, check for the Intel Chipset package as well.

Comment: Nothing changed:"(